# How to update cache with pagination AND sorting - urql, GraphQL

Tags: typescript, caching, graphql, pagination, urql

So I have an app with React, GraphQL and urql. I have a query that returns data (called `readMeanings`), and I have pagination (with a "Load more" button).

The problem is this: because of my pagination, when I reverse the sorting (from `DESC` to `ASC`), the sorted data **is appended** to what I had before, kind of like the "Load more" button is supposed to work.

The data looks like this (it would show `1 2 3` after `10 9 8` when I click "Load more"):

```
DESC: | ASC:
10    | 10
9     | 9
8     | 8
("Load more")
7     | 1
6     | 2
5     | 3
```

When I delete my cache pagination logic, it displays correctly as `1 2 3`, but I obviously want to keep the pagination.

I'm using an urql's [local resolver](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/local-resolvers/) for the pagination cache update:

```ts
resolvers: {
  Query: {
    readMeanings: cursorMeaningPagination(),
  },
},
```

The query `readMeanings` accepts `limit`, `cursor`, used for pagination, and `sorting` (which contains `orderBy`, basically SQL's `ORDER BY`). These inputs are included in the field keys for different versions of the `readMeanings` query fields (see below). The query returns `hasMore`, which is used to hide/show the "Load more" button and `meanings`, which are the `Meaning` records themselves.

On the server side, changing `orderBy` works correctly.

My cache update logic is this (taken from [Ben Awad's fullstack tutorial, around 7h 14m](https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8?t=26048)):

```ts
const cursorMeaningPagination = (): Resolver => {
  return (_parent, fieldArgs, cache, info) => {
    const { parentKey: entityKey, fieldName } = info; // entityKey is a query, fieldName is readMeanings

    const allFields = cache.inspectFields(entityKey); // This gives us all queries
    const fieldInfos = allFields.filter((info) => info.fieldName === fieldName); // This gives us all readMeanings queries in cache
    const size = fieldInfos.length;
    if (size === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const fieldKey = `${fieldName}(${stringifyVariables(fieldArgs)})`;
    const isInCache = cache.resolve(
      cache.resolve(entityKey, fieldKey) as string,
      "meanings"
    ); // If given query is in cache
    let hasMore = true;
    const results: string[] = [];
    info.partial = !isInCache; // Do partial return if not in cache
    // For each particular cached query that we care about
    fieldInfos.forEach((fi) => {
      const key = cache.resolve(entityKey, fi.fieldKey) as Entity; // Get query's field key (includes specific args)
      const data = cache.resolve(key, "meanings") as string[]; // key like: 'posts({"limit":10})'
      const _hasMore = cache.resolve(key, "hasMore");
      if (!_hasMore) {
        hasMore = _hasMore as boolean; // If _hasMore is false
      }
      results.push(...data);
    });
    return { __typename: "PaginatedMeanings", hasMore, meanings: results };
  };
};
```

I see that `data` is taken from the cache, and appended to `results`, and those are `meanings`.

This must be really simple, but I can't guess what exactly I have to do to.

Any help would be appreciated!